# Make parent element be the same height as child element?

Tags: html, css

I have a  heading with a link inside, I want to make the h2 a different background to the link. However, when I add padding to the link, it overflows the parents, how can I make the parent be the height of the child?

```
<h2><a href="#">Something</a></h2>  

h2 {background:blue; }
h2 a {background:red; padding:20px; color:white;}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5LHmr/

Thanks

Comment: a tag is inline, make it display: block or inline-block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `display: inline-block` within the `h2 a { ... }` ruleset: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHmr/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:inline-block`

```
h2 a {
 background:red; 
 padding:20px; 
 color:white;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHmr/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
h2 {background:blue; padding:20px;}
h2 a {background:red; padding:20px; color:white;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LHmr/4/